# Ubuntu /dev/loopX - Way too many mounted units

Tags: mount, filesystem, disk-usage, inode

I am not a very experienced user, specially regarding system's technicalities such as this one. All I know is that when I first installed Ubuntu, I used the command `df -h` to check my disk space. It usually went like this

```
user@laptop:/home$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           585M  1.8M  583M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       457G  104G  331G  24% /
tmpfs           2.9G   29M  2.9G   1% /dev/shm
```

For the last couple of months, however, the results have been as follows:

```
user@laptop:/home$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           585M  1.8M  583M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       457G  104G  331G  24% /
tmpfs           2.9G   29M  2.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop1       17M   17M     0 100% /snap/communitheme/1273
/dev/loop2       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/117
/dev/loop3      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop4      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
/dev/loop6      2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/222
/dev/loop8      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/62
/dev/loop9      2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/199
/dev/loop10     140M  140M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
/dev/loop12     227M  227M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/79
/dev/loop13     227M  227M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/83
/dev/loop14     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop15      43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/701
/dev/loop16     227M  227M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/85
/dev/loop17      88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
/dev/loop21      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop18      88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5548
/dev/loop5       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/124
/dev/loop20      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/43
/dev/loop23      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop22     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/238
/dev/loop24      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop7       17M   17M     0 100% /snap/communitheme/1226
/dev/loop11      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/40
/dev/loop19      17M   17M     0 100% /snap/communitheme/1201
/dev/loop25      87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/5145
/dev/sda1       511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           585M   88K  584M   1% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see, not only do I have 5 temporal filesystems, but also a ridiculous amount of `/dev/loop` entries. I have tried to look for a solution on the internet from time to time. The problem is, I dont even know what is it that I am looking for. The closest I got was to some post talking about inodes, and after barely getting a grasp of what an inode is, I couldn't get anywhere near finding someone undergoing the same situation.

To be honest, I don't know/think this is a problem. But I certainly do not like it. I would like to know **what are these things**, whats their **relationship with the inodes** (if I run `df -i -h` I get a similar result, from what I guess are the corresponding inodes to these mounts), **what is the reason** for their unusual multiplicity, **should I get rid of most of them** and, if so, **how to do it**.

Thanks in advance :D!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of snaps!

Comment: You may want to `alias df='df -x tmpfs -x squashfs'` to supress those loop devices and temporary filesystems (aka ramdisks) from `df`'s output.